# Get the previous raw file from the blob object(hash)

Tags: git

Is there any way to get the previous raw file from the specified blob object(hash).
In other words, when a blob hash of a file is changed from `fd871b5` to `6732f18`, I want to get a content of `fd871b5`.
But unfortunately, `fd871b5` is not public, so I try to use caret `^` with the post changed blob hash.
According to the outputs below, caret `^` is not working against a blob object.
Any ideas?

```
$ git show -- README.md
commit 9f38e2d9e6ca81341fecf82d881cf629effb4be2
-- snip --
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index fd871b5..6732f18 100644
-- snip --
$ git show 6732f18^
error: object 6732f18f21f8b4b7ffe0c015803d7cd09c597337 is a blob, not a commit
error: object 6732f18f21f8b4b7ffe0c015803d7cd09c597337 is a blob, not a commit
fatal: ambiguous argument '6732f18^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Use case details:
In some OSS projects, the released patches have a blob object which is not public, neither commit-id.
When `pre-blob` and `commit-id` is not public, and only available is `post-blob`, I want to retrieve an exact same file corresponding to `<pre-blob>`.

Comment: If a blob is not reachable via a commit, then you could not see it. Moreover "parent of a blob" is not defined, there is no such thing in git.

Answer (score 3):

Only commits have parents.  Resolve what's at that path in the commit's parent:

```
git rev-parse 9f38e2d9e6ca81341fecf82d881cf629effb4be2^:README.md
```

to show its id,

```
git show 9f38e2d9e6ca81341fecf82d881cf629effb4be2^:README.md
```

to show its content.

Comment: Thanks. If commit-id is public, this command is very useful. I'd like to know if commit-id is not public, is there any way to retrieve the previous raw file from post blob object. sorry for lack of my use case.

Comment: What are you referring to with "not public" here? Please be concrete about the actual situation you find yourself in.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the hash of the blob of interest and the blob still exists in the repo (i.e. it may be a dangling object, but it hasn't yet been garbage-collected), use

```
git cat-file -p <hash>
```

To fix ideas, here is an example:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jubobs/Desktop/test-git/.git/
$ echo foo > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "Write 'foo' to README"
[master (root-commit) 73ece26] Write 'foo' to README
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo bar >> README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "Append 'bar' to README"
[master 7ac5ae9] Append 'bar' to README
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
test-git(master)$ git show -- README
commit 7ac5ae95b49c7e493119f46fb8150c437a200df3 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Jubobs <xxxxxxxx>
Date:   Sun Jun 11 01:04:22 2017 +0100

    Append 'bar' to README

diff --git a/README b/README
index 257cc56..3bd1f0e 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 foo
+bar
$ git cat-file -p 257cc56
foo
$ git cat-file -p 3bd1f0e
foo
bar
```